# while mysql_fetch_array loop doesn't run

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
$itemSelect="select * from items where gender='men' and type='suite'";
$itemQuery=mysql_query($itemSelect) or die(mysql_error());
$num=count($itemQuery);
echo $num;
if($itemQuery)
{
    echo "I am here";
    echo "<table>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($itemQuery))
    {
            $photo=$row['photo'];
            $name=$row['name'];
            $price=$row['price'];
            echo "<tr><td>". $photo ."</td><td>" .$name ."</td><td>" .$price ."</td>     </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "There is some mistacke";
    die();
}
```

So here `$num=count($itemQuery);` shows me that there is 1 item that satisfies the search but the loop is never executed what could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: WHy do you all people dont like foreach loop? isnt it easier to under stand?

     `foreach ($itemQuery as $value) {



    }`

Comment: @Michael Because you can't iterate over a mysql result resource...?!

Comment: @Michael If you see clearly `$itemQuery` is a resultset and he is fetching the records, `foreach` will not make a difference. @OP can you do a `echo mysql_error();` after executing the query?

Comment: What happens if you replace count($itemQuery) with mysql_num_rows($itemQuery). Also, are you sure the loop doesn't execute? Maybe photo, name and price are NULL?

Comment: Hm, that is weird it returns me 0 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting `1` is because of this code:

```
$num=count($itemQuery);
echo $num;
```

`count` is a function to get the number of items in an array. If you pass anything that isn't an array (or doesn't implement the ICountable interface), then `count` returns always `1`.

So this piece of code is incorrect in that it shows 1, while that number isn't at all related to the number of rows returned.

The query itself looks fine to me, although I cannot validate it against your actual database.  If you see the message `"I am here"`, then your query executed fine, but didn't return any rows. If you don't see that message, then something else went wrong. You can use `mysql_error` to try to find any errors in that case.

Comment: mysql_num_rows would be the right one :)

--> $num=mysql_num_rows($itemQuery);

Comment: OK that makes sense thanks, but to be honest there is an item in my database that satisfies the search so why the loop still doesn't run?

Comment: When there is no mysql_error, check your SQL string and your WHERE. Is the gender really "men"?

Answer (score 0):

```
$count= mysql_num_rows($itemQuery);
echo $count;
if($count > 0)){
    echo "<table>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($itemQuery)){
        $photo=$row['photo'];
        $name=$row['name'];
        $price=$row['price'];
        echo "<tr><td>". $photo ."</td><td>" .$name ."</td><td>" .$price ."</td>     </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}else{
    echo "there are no results";
    die();
}
```